Change Package Name on Google Play
I have created an internal test release with a wrong package name on google play by uploading an aab. I haven't created a production release yet, but wanted to correct the package name. Where can I change the package name? If it's not possible, will I need to create a new app on google play and go over the setup processes again?

I think you need to create a new app even after uploading the app to internal test if you need to change the package name. Here is a similar question I found.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/255035531/change-app-package-name-before-publishing-the-app?hl=en#:~:text=You%20won't%20be%20able,based%20on%20the%20package%20name.
